# Laravel webpack including custom javascript

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I do the below, I get 'Uncaught Reference Error Slideout is not defined' in my console.

**In resources/js/app.js:**

```
require('./slideout');
```

**Code in blade template right before `</body>`:**

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    var slideout = new Slideout({
        'panel': document.getElementById('panel'),
        'menu': document.getElementById('menu'),
        'padding': 256,
        'tolerance': 70
    });

});
</script>
```

If I check the generated app.js file I can see that all the Slideout code is there. So it's included properly.

But if I do this (add slideout.min.js through CDN), it works:

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slideout/1.0.1/slideout.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    var slideout = new Slideout({
        'panel': document.getElementById('panel'),
        'menu': document.getElementById('menu'),
        'padding': 256,
        'tolerance': 70
    });

});
</script>
```

Why doesn't it work when the Slideout code is in the app.js file?

Comment: If you add your slideout js inside your app.js then make sure it dependencies are imported first. So you CDN needs to be above your app.js

Comment: I would like to include slideout JS in my app.js and not use the CDN. As I'm relatively new to this: what do you mean by 'make sure it dependencies are imported first'?

Comment: Did you make sure the browser actually loads the new `app.js` with your changes and not the old one from the cache?

Comment: Yep I did a hard refresh and double checked the contents.